# How to fire a setState function in react from child componenet to parent componenet with data from a button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, components

I have a parent componenet called FormLeadBuilderEdit, and it is use useState hook I pass the setState(setCards in my case) function down to to my child componenet called Card. For some reason in the child componenet when I call setCard("vale") the state doesnt update. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be great

Thanks

FormLeadBuilderEdit Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Card } from "./Card";

const FormLeadBuilderEdit = ({ params }) => {

  const inputs = [
    {
      inputType: "shortText",
      uniId: Random.id(),
      label: "First Name:",
      value: "Kanye",
    },
    {
      inputType: "phoneNumber",
      uniId: Random.id(),
      label: "Cell Phone Number",
      value: "2813348004",
    },
    {
      inputType: "email",
      uniId: Random.id(),
      label: "Work Email",
      value: "kanye@usa.gov",
    },
    {
      inputType: "address",
      uniId: Random.id(),
      label: "Home Address",
      value: "123 White House Avenue",
    },
    {
      inputType: "multipleChoice",
      uniId: Random.id(),
      label: "Preferred Method of Contact",
      value: "2813348004",
      multipleChoice: {
        uniId: Random.id(),
        options: [
          {
            uniId: Random.id(),
            label: "Email",
            checked: false,
          },
          {
            uniId: Random.id(),
            label: "Cell Phone",
            checked: false,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      inputType: "dropDown",
      uniId: Random.id(),
      label: "How did you find us?",
      value: "2813348004",
      dropDown: {
        uniId: Random.id(),
        options: [
          {
            uniId: Random.id(),
            label: "Google",
          },
          {
            uniId: Random.id(),
            label: "Referral",
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ];
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  setCards(inputs)

  return (
    <>
      <Card
        key={card.uniId + index}
        index={index}
        id={card.uniId}
        input={card}
        setCards={setCards}
        params={params}
        cards={cards}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default FormLeadBuilderEdit;
```

Cart Component

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Random } from "meteor/random";

export const Card = ({ setCards, cards }) => {
    const addOption = () => {
    const newCards = cards;

    newCards.map((card) => {
      if (card.inputType === "multipleChoice") {
        card.multipleChoice.options.push({
          uniId: Random.id(),
          label: "test",
          checked: false,
        });
      }
    });

    console.log(newCards);

    setCards(newCards);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={addOption} type="button">
        Add Option
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: `map` return new array copy. Try this `const newCard = ...your card map code;
setCards(newCard)`

Comment: According to your logic, `cards.map` will always return an empty array you don't really add any option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React uses variable reference as a way to know which state has been changed and then triggers re-renders.

So one of the first thing you would like to know about state is that "Do not mutate state directly".
Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Instead, produce a new state that contains changes (which has different variable reference) :

```
const addOption = () => {
    const newCards = cards.map((card) => {
      if (card.inputType === "multipleChoice") {          
        const newOption = {
          uniId: Random.id(),
          label: "test",
          checked: false,
        };
        card.multipleChoice.options = [...card.multipleChoice.options, newOption];
      }
      return card;
    });

    setCards(newCards);
    // setCards(cards); <- this refer to the current `cards` which will not trigger re-render
  };
```

Comment: I followed your pattern but it console logged undefined, so I modified it slighly seen in my question above, but my state change is still not rerendering my componenet

Comment: Hi, I've edited the answer. I guess you want to trigger the re-render of the options array. Also noted that the `map` function needs to return something

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by one of the users, you are passing an empty `cards` array on which you are performing `map` operation which not surprisingly returns an empty array itself, hence you are not getting any state changes.

The logic of passing the `setCards` is correct.

Here is a small example where state changes are taking place and also showing.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  return (
    <>
      <Card
        setCards={setCards}
        cards={cards}
      />
      <p>{cards.toString()}</p>
    </>
  );
};



const Card = ({ setCards, cards }) => {
  const addOption = () => {
    setCards(["1","2"]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={addOption} type="button">
        Add Option
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Screenshot:

[image: changing state from child component]

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-jackson-7wslt?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Sorry my actual code was much larger so I didn't show where I inititally set the state. I have added my modifications, above, it will console log the correct (newCards) but the state change never rerenders the page

Comment: if possible then do consider posting this project on CodeSandbox and share the link

Comment: ok I will try but' its a meteor project so it has some dependencies that Im not sure I can setup